# Does Visual C# 2010 Express need Windows 7 SDK?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, visual-studio-express

To create programs with Visual C#, do I need to install the Windows 7 SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you only need the SDK if you want the reference dlls without installing VS 2010.  For example, you might want to install it on a build server.

Well, or if you want anything from the SDK specifically, like the code samples.

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

No, but it does contain useful tools like FxCop, which I find quite useful just for catching silly mistakes that don't break your program, but maybe slow it down or make it more difficult to maintain.